# PySpark How to fill NaN value with an array in streaming?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What I'm doing is to fill Null value within a dataframe with an array in a streaming environment. My situation is this:
[image]

I need to fill the null value with the array in the last row, the one with id = -1. What I've tried to do is the following operation:

```
concat.withColumn('object_values2',
  F.when(concat['object_values'].isNull(), 
         array([lit(x) for x in concat.where(col("object_values").isNotNull()).rdd.collect()[0]['object_values']])
)\
  .otherwise(concat['object_values'])).show()
```

**That doesn't work in streaming!** When I use this code in streaming I got an error message *Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()*
My question is: How can avoid the *collect* operation in streaming to solve my problem?

Comment: Why not storing them as nulls and replace null by that array when using the data later?

Comment: Thanks @blackbishop for the answer, but can you show me an example?